# Irreproducible Errors using sapply

Tags: r

I have a situation where I'm converting data from character to integer. However on one machine, the same code produces a different result than on another machine and I'm at a loss for why. Here's an example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = "1", b = "2", c = "3", 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Now, on my local machine, the following works as expected:

```
df[,c("a","b")] <- sapply(df[,c("a","b")], as.integer)

str(df)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: int 1
 $ b: int 2
 $ c: chr "3"
```

But on the remote machine, this same line of code returns:

```
df[,c("a","b")] <- sapply(df[,c("a","b")], as.integer)
str(df)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: chr "1"
 $ b: chr "2"
 $ c: chr "3"
```

I find this very strange, and I can't think of any good reasons for it. I looked at sys.info() and all of our packages are the same between the two.  Same with the locale. The only difference is the version of R and the version of Ubuntu

My machine: R 3.2.2, Ubuntu 15.10

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 15.10

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C                 LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=C
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C               LC_MONETARY=C              LC_MESSAGES=en_CA.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_CA.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages: 
[1] dplyr_0.4.3          tidyr_0.4.1          data.table_1.9.6    
[4] RMySQL_0.9-3         DBI_0.3.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.3       codetools_0.2-14  psych_1.5.8       foreach_1.4.3
 [5] assertthat_0.1    plyr_1.8.3        chron_2.3-47      R6_2.1.2
 [9] magrittr_1.5      lazyeval_0.1.10   doParallel_1.0.10 iterators_1.0.8
[13] tools_3.2.2       yaml_2.1.13       parallel_3.2.2    mnormt_1.5-3
```

Remote: R 3.2.4, Ubuntu 12.04

```
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=C            LC_COLLATE=C        
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C        LC_MESSAGES=C        LC_PAPER=C           LC_NAME=C           
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C         LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=C     LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.4.3          tidyr_0.4.1          data.table_1.9.6    
[4] RMySQL_0.9-3         DBI_0.3.1           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.3      codetools_0.2-14 psych_1.4.8.11   foreach_1.4.2    assertthat_0.1  
 [6] plyr_1.8.1       chron_2.3-47     R6_2.0.1         magrittr_1.5     lazyeval_0.1.10 
[11] doParallel_1.0.8 iterators_1.0.7  tools_3.2.4      yaml_2.1.13      parallel_3.2.4
```

Thoughts?

Comment: At least maybe say what the two R versions are so that it's possible (in theory) for other people to test?

Comment: @joran right you are. Updated!

Comment: Works as-expected on mine, Windows 7, R 3.0.3 ... is it at all possible you made a mistake on the other machine?

Comment: @Joe The remote machine pulls from a git repo, so it's not at all possible.

Comment: I got the same as your local machine on Win7 3.2.3 and Win10 3.2.4

Comment: Are both machines the same OS?

Comment: @Joe Ah good point. One is Ubuntu 15.10 the other is Ubuntu 12.04. Still.

Comment: Add the output from `sessionInfo` from both machines. Also check the definitions of `sapply` and `as.integer` are (roughly) the same on both.  My guess is that the remote machine is loading some package/code that messes with one/both of those functions.

Comment: can you try running this via `R CMD BATCH --vanilla` on both local and remote?

Comment: @BenBolker I don't have direct access to the other machine.

Comment: results of (1) `str(df)` before running `sapply` (2) `find("sapply")` ? maybe try the dreaded `rm(list=ls())` ?

Comment: @BenBolker  result of str(df) is what you see above in the question. I'll try the `rm(list=ls())`

Comment: I wanted `str(df)` *after* you created the df but *before* you ran `sapply(...)` on it ... to see if perhaps the object creation itself was happening differently

Comment: Any particular reason you chose to omit the first 3 lines of output from `sessionInfo`?  The platform may be relevant.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich No reason. Added.

Comment: It was a lexical scoping issue. I still can't figure out why it occured on their machine and not mine, but when I moved the offending code up a level, it worked as expected. Rather than delete, I'm going to vote to close as there was a lot of useful steps to take in finding the problem in the comments here.

Comment: please vote to close as irreproducible.